The acceleration of the end point of a hinged rod
Say I have a rod which is pivoted at one end and dropped down. If the tangential acceleration of the end of the rod, which is straight downward when the rod is just released, is calculated using torque, its acceleration is 3g/2. I was curious as to how this was possible as gravity is responsible only for providing this acceleration. I'm new to rotational mechanics, excuse me if I'm wrong.

Are you asking how the end of the rod can have an acceleration greater than g?

This question is an exact duplicate of: Is there a maximum angular acceleration due to gravity for a given radius?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please refer to my answer in the linked question, which is an exact duplicate of yours, and answers your question too.
